# Python how to stop adding into list after hitting certain criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm doing a project whereby a user has to input the value. The loop should end if the user key in the value of more than 300 for 3 times. If the user key in a value lesser than 300, a warning message should be prompted. And another criteria is that I need to allow the user to get out of the loop if the user do not meet the condition above. For now, I tried to do by using the list but my code doesn't seem to count the number of inputs.

```
list1 = list()
counter = 1 
while counter <= 3: 
    ask = float(input("Please enter each of the value: ")) 
    while ask != "":
        list1.append(str(ask))
        ask = float(input("Please enter each of the value: "))
        if ask >= 50:
            counter += 1 
        else:
            print("Value must be more than 300. If you do not meet the criteria, please press 'enter'. ")
print(list1)
```

The following code is my original code which doesn't take into account of the minimum input value.

```
counter = 1 
while counter <= 3:
    ask = float(input("Please enter each of the value: ")) 
    if ask >= 50:
        counter += 1 
    else:
        print("Value must be more than 300 ")
```

I would appreciate if anyone of you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your inner while loop can't exit since ' "" ' (your exit signal) cannot be converted to float. Instead it will raise a ValueError.
One possible solution to this would be to try converting input to float and except the ValueError. It could look something like this.

```
list1 = list()
counter = 1
while counter <= 3:
    try:
       ask = float(input("Please enter each of the value: "))
    except ValueError:
       break
    list1.append(str(ask))
    if ask >= 50:
        counter += 1 
    else:
        print("Value must be more than 300. If you do not meet the criteria, please press 'enter'. ")

print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the program doesn't work as you want because you made two while loops:
the first while's condition is `while counter<=3`, ok but then you made another while which condition is `ask !=""`, so the program will run inside this second while loop until the condition is no more true and the first while does not "see" the counter's changes.

By the way, I think you can simply use only one while loop(the first one), and write an if condition that verify the value(>300).

When you try to cast a string element into a float type it will throw an error if the value could not be casted to that type, you could use a try-except block.

```
while counter < 3:
      try:
           ask = float(input("xxxxx")
           if ask >= 50:
               counter += 1
           else:
               print("xxxxx")
      except ValueError:
           break
print(list1)
```